# ASP.NET Core - Change height of form text box

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a "contact me" form in ASP.NET Core that will have a name, email, subject and message field. I have a few chunks of code like this in my view for the text boxes:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Message" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Message" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Message" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

For this message text box, I would like the the text box to be larger vertically than my previous ones. How do I do this without changing the other boxes?

Comment: Style it using css (it has an `id="Message"`)

Comment: So I'm new to CSS/HTML stuff; when you say style it using css do I go into my site.css file and make a custom element called Message?

Comment: Yes, or you can do it in a separate file (but it needs to be after bootstrap css), or in the view (between `<style>` tags or even inline (`<input ... style="height: ??px;" />`

Comment: I added the style tag inline as follows: `style ="height: 100px;` but the issue is that when you click in the box, or press tab from the previous box the cursor starts at the middle of the box.

Comment: Of course (a textbox can only have one line). If you want multiple lines of text, then use a `textarea` element

Comment: use `textarea` instead of using `input` like this : `<textarea asp-for="Message" class="form-control">Enter text here...</textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change input field into textarea for the message. Textarea element has multiple rows.